# Explanation on Adding items to a ListBox in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make a simple Windows 8/RT app for the store and i have a question about adding items to a ListBox.

In my MainPage i have this code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.brain = new MainController();
        LoadData();
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        brain.GetNotesRepoFile().ReadFile();
        Debug(""+brain.GetNotesRepoFile().GetNotesList().Count);
        for(int i = 0; i < brain.GetNotesRepoFile().GetNotesList().Count; i++)
        {
           notesListBox.Items.Add( // code here );
        }
    }
 }


public class NotesRepositoryFile
{
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public NotesRepositoryFile()
    {
        this.notesRepository = new List<Note>();
    }
    // Read from file
    public async void ReadFile()
    {
        // settings for the file
        var path = @"Files\Notes.txt";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        // acquire file
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (var line in readThis)
        {
            notesRepository.Add(new Note(line.Split(';')[0], line.Split(';')[1]));
            // check if the item was added
            Debug.WriteLine("Added: " + notesRepository[notesRepository.Count - 1].ToString());
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("File read successfully");
    }
```

}

**My Output is:**

0

Added: Test1

Added: Test2

File read successfully

What am i trying to do here is read strings from a file and add them using Items.Add to a listBox. But since the size of the array is 0, even though the items were added successfully that doesnt work.

I dont understand why *Debug(""+brain.GetNotesRepoFile().GetNotesList().Count);* is executed **before** *brain.GetNotesRepoFile().ReadFile();* since clearly that is not the case.

Also why does this solution work, and the above doesnt ??

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.brain = new MainController();
        ReadFile();
    }
    // Read from file
    public async void ReadFile()
    {
        // settings for the file
        var path = @"Files\Notes.txt";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        // acquire file
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (var line in readThis)
        {
            brain.AddNote(line.Split(';')[0], line.Split(';')[1]);
            notesListBox.Items.Add(brain.GetNotesRepoFile().GetNotesList()[brain.GetNotesRepoFile().GetNotesList().Count - 1].ToString());
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("File read successfully");
    }
```

}

Comment: why won`t you just create simple List collection and set it as item source of the list ?

Comment: Well that is a solution, but i still don't get it why the above solution doesn't work.

Comment: Without running your code I would hazard a guess that the thread that is running your ReadFile method is not completing before the LoadData method completes. That would be why you are seeing those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, usage of async and await is wrong is you code, please change according to following codes

First, in NotesRepositoryFile class

```
public async Task<bool> ReadFile()
{
   //Your code
    if (notesRepository.Count > 0) return true;
            return false;
}
```

Second in the MainPage

```
public async void LoadData()
{
    bool HasNote = await brain.GetNotesRepoFile().ReadFile();

    if (HasNote)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < brain.GetNotesRepoFile().notesRepository.Count; i++)
        {
                //Your code
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you don't want to return Task<bool> you can instead change the void just to a Task (public async Task ReadFile()) - await will then work fine with this.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the time to help me out !